# Is a father mevatel the Mitzva of Pidyon Haben by keeping the 5 silver coins?

Tags: pidyon-haben

During the Pidyon Haben ceremony the Kohen asks the father מה בעית טפי ליתן לי בנך בכורך... או לפדותו בעד חמש סלעים. A free translation of this is 
-what would you rather do, give me your first born or redeem him for 5 coins?-

If the father chooses to keep the coins over his son, is he mevatel the Mitzvah of redeeming his Bechor? Meaning, are there 2 parts to this Mitzvah - a)keeping the coins or b)redeeming his son and as long as he picks one of them he is Mekayam his Mitzvah, or is the Mitzvah to actually redeem him from the Kohen and if this was not done he loses the Mitzvah. If we say he lost the Mitzvah can he rectify it by redeeming his child at a later point?

Comment: You seem to be focusing on the encounter between the kohen and the father suggesting that the encounter itself might exempt the father from pidyon, regardless of his activities. AFAIK the encounter itself does not have halakhic import; just the transaction. If the father fail to redeem his son, he can redeem him later. If he doesn't, the son must redeem himself.

Comment: I don't consider this a duplicate question. I am asking from the Mitzvah point of view not who can raise the child. I want to analyze the Mitzvah. This is similar to a comment made yesterday by someone that just because you come to the same answer in conclusion doesn't make it a duplicate question.

Comment: It's the same issue. There is no choice about who should raise the kid or how to do the Mitzva, since the discussion isn't real. The Mitzva is to give the priest 5 Shekels. No ifs ands or buts.

Comment: @Earl Don't you mean to ask whether he is yotzei the mitzvah?

Comment: @DoubleAA This is clearly not a duplicate of the other question. It should be reopened.  ... If you have an answer to this unique question, as your comment above suggests, I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA You have an answer to his question, not a demonstration that a complete answer to that question necessarily addresses this one (which, by the way, the answers there don't).